# Changing date time format in R

Tags: r

I have a table with two columns "start" and "end" containing both dates and times of the respective start and end period as follows:

```
Sr. No.    Start                 End
1          22May2001:00:00:00    27May2001:23:59:59
2          28May2001:00:00:00    26Jun2001:23:59:59
```

I would like to convert above date time in the following format (ISO8601 with time stamp):

```
Sr. No.    Start                 End
1          2001-05-22 00:00:00   2001-05-27 23:59:59
2          2001-05-28 00:00:00   2001-06-26 23:59:59
```

I have used the code available at this link: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html

```
View(my_table)
str(my_table)
my_table$startD <- as.Date(my_table$start, "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
my_table$startT <- strptime(my_table$start, format = "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

So far, my attempt gave me two columns like this:

```
StartD       StartT
2001-05-22   2001-05-22
```

Which is not desirable. Could someone please suggest me to convert the date time in desired format through above or any alternate approach?

Comment: You need a datetime class (i.e. POSIXct or POSIXlt). You can parse with `as.POSIXct` or `strptime`, e.g. `library(dplyr) ; df %>% mutate_at(-1, as.POSIXct, format = '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')` or the equivalent. Note the printing for both at midnight omits the time part, but it's still stored.

Comment: as.Date only converts the date and not the time.  Try: my_table$startD <- as.POSIXct(my_table$start, "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")

Comment: @Dave2e: When I tried to use "as.POSIXct()". I encountered an error: Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format,. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: You need to specify the parameter name: `format = "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S"`, because otherwise it assumes the parsing string is the second parameter, which is for setting the time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer form for clarity, you need a datetime class, which in R means either POSIXct or POSIXlt. Usually we use `as.POSIXct` and `strptime` for parsing strings into each class, respectively (`as.POSIXlt` exists, but rarely gets used), though there are lubridate alternatives if you like.

At its most basic,

```
my_table$Start <- as.POSIXct(my_table$Start, format = '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
my_table$End <- as.POSIXct(my_table$End, format = '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')

my_table
##   Sr.No.      Start                 End
## 1      1 2001-05-22 2001-05-27 23:59:59
## 2      2 2001-05-28 2001-06-26 23:59:59
```

Note you need to specify the name of the `format` string, as the second parameter of `as.POSIXct` is actually `tz` (for setting the time zone). Also note that while `Start` looks like it's missing a time, that's because the print methods for POSIX*t don't print times at midnight, though they are still stored.

If you'd like to change both in a single line, you could use

```
my_table[-1] <- lapply(my_table[,-1], as.POSIXct, format = '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```

or in dplyr (which prefers POSIXct over POSIXlt):

```
library(dplyr)

my_table %>% mutate_at(-1, as.POSIXct, format = '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```

both of which return exactly the same thing. You could also use [`lubridate::dmy_hms`, which parses to POSIXct](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.6.0/topics/ymd_hms):

```
library(lubridate)

my_table$Start <- dmy_hms(my_table$Start)    # or lapply like above
my_table$End <- dmy_hms(my_table$End)

# or dplyr
my_table %>% mutate_at(-1, dmy_hms)
```

which also return the same thing.

---

#### Data

```
my_table <- structure(list(Sr.No. = 1:2, Start = structure(1:2, .Label = c("22May2001:00:00:00", 
    "28May2001:00:00:00"), class = "factor"), End = structure(c(2L, 
    1L), .Label = c("26Jun2001:23:59:59", "27May2001:23:59:59"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sr.No.", 
    "Start", "End"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

```
my_table <- "22May2001:22:02:50"

my_table <- strptime(as.character(my_table), "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")

my_table <- format(my_table, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

str(my_table)
```

Comment: It's more useful to leave datetimes as POSIX*t than to convert back to character with `format`.