# How to change column Date Time format in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with over 8.8 million obs that have several columns with date and time in the same cell. I have tried the solution to the below question but I could not get it to work

[Changing date time format in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38594177/changing-date-time-format-in-r)

**Below is how my data looks**

```
> head(dat)
                     dat
1 12/31/2018 11:59:46 PM
2 12/31/2018 11:59:20 PM
3 12/31/2018 11:58:45 PM
4 12/31/2018 11:58:14 PM
5 12/31/2018 11:57:42 PM
6 12/31/2018 11:57:41 PM
```

I would like to convert it into the R format of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Running this code returns all the values to NA

```
dat$dat <- as.POSIXct(dat$dat, format = '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```

Is there a way to convert it to R format so I can do some date and time analysis

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
as.POSIXct(df$dat, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2018-12-31 23:59:46 UTC" "2018-12-31 23:59:20 UTC" "2018-12-31 23:58:45 UTC" 
#    "2018-12-31 23:58:14 UTC" "2018-12-31 23:57:42 UTC" "2018-12-31 23:57:41 UTC"
```

Or with `lubridate`

```
lubridate::mdy_hms(df$dat)
```

Also `anytime` can be used if you don't want to worry about formats

```
anytime::anytime(df$dat)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(dat = structure(6:1, .Label = c("12/31/2018 11:57:41 PM", 
"12/31/2018 11:57:42 PM", "12/31/2018 11:58:14 PM", "12/31/2018 11:58:45 PM", 
"12/31/2018 11:59:20 PM", "12/31/2018 11:59:46 PM"), class = "factor")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I used the 1st option and does what I need it to. Thanks!